# How to save a selected option in a var

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

I need to save a selected option in a var. How i can to do this?

```
<%= f.collection_select(:department_id , Department.all, :id, :name, options ={:prompt => "-Select department"}) %>
```

Comment: Where? A Javascript variable? In a controller?

Comment: I need to save in department_id

Comment: It is saved in department_id (the field name is more complex because you are using form_for or something similar). Its not a variable. It's a form field. Where will you use it?. It will be passed to the controller in the params hash. Or you can use it in a Javascript function before submitting.

Comment: I want to show that such a teacher is part of such a department

Comment: Where do you want to show that a teacher is part o a department? (when you select the department it is already shown on the page, but I guess you mean something else and you are not clear in describing your problem). Where is this piece of code you wrote? Your problem is just showing this or saving the relation in the database?.  Please put some more relevant information in the question such as your models, the form (not just this field), etc.